# Sorting array elements in Smalltalk

Tags: arrays, sorting, oop, object, smalltalk

I am trying to sort the contents of the Array by alphabetical order by evaluating its first and third elements. I tried to use the 2nd and 3rd element in the array to evaluate and sort the array. But still I wasn't able to get the desired result.

Here's the content of the collection

```
#(#('Philippines' 'Davao' 'Durian')
#('Philippines' 'Cebu' 'Mango')
#('Philippines' 'Zambales' 'Lanzones)
#('Thailand' 'Bangkok'  'Durian')
#('Thailand' 'Phuket' 'Mango')
#('Vietnam' 'Ho chi min' 'Banana')
#('Vietnam' 'Hanoi' 'Mango'))
```

Here's what I did:

```
newArray := arrValues asArray.

newContent := newArray asSortedCollection: [ :ea :each | (ea at: 2) < (each at: 3) and: [ (ea at: 3) < (each at: 3)  ] ].
```

Here's my output:

```
#(#('Vietnam' 'Ho chi min' 'Banana')
#('Thailand' 'Bangkok'  'Durian')
#('Philippines' 'Davao' 'Durian')
#('Vietnam' 'Hanoi' 'Mango'))
#('Thailand' 'Phuket' 'Mango')
#('Philippines' 'Zambales' 'Lanzones)
#('Philippines' 'Cebu' 'Mango')
```

The output should be:

```
#(#('Vietnam' 'Ho chi min' 'Banana')
#('Thailand' 'Bangkok'  'Durian')
#('Philippines' 'Davao' 'Durian')
#('Philippines' 'Cebu' 'Mango')
#('Vietnam' 'Hanoi' 'Mango'))
#('Thailand' 'Phuket' 'Mango')
#('Philippines' 'Zambales' 'Lanzones)
```

Comment: The output you are asking for ("The output should be:") is not sorted, so nobody can actually give you a correct answer that would match that. In each column you have something wrong ('Vietnam' above 'Thailand', 'Ho chi min' above 'Bankok'; 'Mango' above 'Lanzones')

Comment: @PeterUhnak no: it's because third element is used as primary predicate, then second...

Comment: @aka.nice if third column is used as primary, why is `Mango` above `Lanzones` The last time I checked the alphabet, `L` comes before `M`.

Comment: @PeterUhnak :) I should verify the last time I consulted the ophtalmologist...

Answer (score 3):

In Squeak and Pharo Smalltalk, you can write something like:

```
^arrValues sorted: #third ascending , #second ascending
```

or in Visualworks

```
^arrValues sorted:
     [:subArray | subArray at: 3] ascending ,
     [:subArray | subArray at: 2] ascending
```

We may thank Travis Griggs for introducing those nice SortFunction which give these good looking functional styles

He published this in his Objology blog
http://objology.blogspot.com/2012/05/tag-memoizedfunctions.html
and probably in earlier posts

Comment: Ah, I found the earlier posts http://objology.blogspot.fr/2010/11/tag-sortfunctions.html
 and http://objology.blogspot.fr/2010/11/tag-sortfunctions-redux.html

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic problem with sorting that doesn't depend on the language used. Do you have experience with other languages? If so, how would you write it there?

Consider a test like the following:

```
[:a :b | (a at: 2) < (b at: 2) or: [
    (a at: 2) = (b at: 2) and: [(a at: 3) < (b at: 3)]]]
```

Alternatively, if you know that everything is a String you can do the following:

```
[:a :b | ((at at: 2) , (a at: 3)) < ((b at: 2) , (b at: 3))]
```

Also, please note the name of the language is `Smalltalk` (without a capital 'T').

Comment: I think that OP wish `(a at: 3) , (a at: 2) < ((b at: 3) , (b at: 2))`, but it's a detail

Comment: "This is a classic problem with sorting that doesn't depend on the language used. Do you have experience with other languages? If so, how would you write it there?" – Actually, in many other languages (for example Ruby), collections are lexicographically ordered, so you would just need to do (e.g. Ruby `an_array.sort_by {|_, second, third| [third, second] }`).

Comment: I tried to do what you recommend, but still, it's not displaying the right output.

Answer (score 0):

The output should be:

```
#(#('Vietnam' 'Ho chi min' 'Banana')
#('Thailand' 'Bangkok'  'Durian')
#('Philippines' 'Davao' 'Durian')
#('Philippines' 'Zambales' 'Lanzones)
#('Philippines' 'Cebu' 'Mango')
#('Vietnam' 'Hanoi' 'Mango'))
#('Thailand' 'Phuket' 'Mango')
```

To get this, you could use

```
newArray := arrValues asArray.

newContent := newArray asSortedCollection: 
    [ :ea :each |
      (ea at: 3) < (each at: 3)
         or: [ (ea at: 3) = (each at: 3) and: [(ea at: 2) < (each at: 2)] ]
    ].
```

or the typical and slightly more readable version

```
newArray := arrValues asArray.

newContent := newArray asSortedCollection: 
    [ :a :b |
      (a at: 3) < (b at: 3)
         or: [ (a at: 3) = (b at: 3) and: [(a at: 2) < (b at: 2)] ]
    ].
```